# Hiding arrow on scroll- Better approach?

Tags: html, css, html-table, scroll

I'm trying to hide the arrow that appears on top of selected header as shown below.
[image]

on scroll I'm trying to hide when the arrow appears on the header **Company** as the first column is sticky.

```
.hide-arrow{
    height: 19px;
    width: 91px;
    z-index: 9999 !important;
    position: sticky;
    left: 3px;
    opacity: unset;
    background: white;
}
```

I'm wondering if this is the right approach to do as this needs to create a **div** that needs to occupy space to hide the arrow on scroll.

```
 <tr>
        <div class="hide-arrow"></div>
        <th style="left:3px">Company</th>
        <th>Contact
          <div class="arrow-position">
          <span class="module-img"> <i class="icon-long-arrow-down"></i>
          </span>
          </div>
        </th>
        <th>Country</th>
        <th>Code</th>
        <th>Language</th>
        <th>Country</th>
        <th>Code</th>
        <th>Language</th>
      </tr>
```

Please find the working plunker [here](http://next.plnkr.co/edit/bSSdALY2GWiBBEZQ?open=lib%2Fscript.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you're okay with the use of jquery.

```
        $(window).scroll(function() {
        var scrollVal = $(this).scrollLeft();   //the scrolled window value in px.
                    if ( scrollVal > 150 ) {
                         $('.arrow-position').css({'display':'none'});
                    } else {
                        $('.arrow-position').css({'display':'block'});
                    }
                });
            });
```

PS: Kindly set **$(window)** to **whatever you are going to scroll i.e. .table i think** and also **change static 150 scroll value to whatever suits you**.
Hope It helps!!

Comment: I wanted to integrate this functionality in typescript.So not sure if I'm able to use this code as it's jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can get that done smoothly without Jquery.
so here's an answer including Jquery. This way you can also adjust where you would like the arrow to fade out.

HTML:

`<div class="top"><div class="title">↓</div></div>`

CSS:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 1000px;
}

.top {
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  opacity: 1;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: #000;
}

.title {
position: absolute;
top: 60%;
left: 100px;
}
```

JQuery:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
$(".top").css("opacity", 1 - $(window).scrollTop() / 250);
});

/*win.scroll(function(){
scrollPosition = win.scrollTop();
scrollRatio = 1 - scrollPosition / 300;
$(".top").css("opacity", scrollRatio);
*/

/*$(window).scroll(function(){
var scrollVar = $(window).scrollTop();
$('.top').css("opacity", 1 - scrollVar/300);
})*/
```

Adjusted from [this Codepen](https://codepen.io/nickcil/pen/sfutl)